# Jaspersoft displays incorrect data from query

Tags: sql, mysql, jasper-reports

I am working in Jaspersoft Studio to make a report. I have an SQL query that looks like this:

```
 SELECT  
     a.article_name, 
     a.invoice_id, 
     a.article_id
 FROM db.articles a
 WHERE a.invoice_id = 1;
```

I have tested this query in mysql workbech and it works as expected.
But in the table in the report I get different results.

I have checked and am sure that parameters I'm passing are defenetly correct.

Comment: ___Small but relevant point___ That query will not run, `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'a.article_name' in 'field list'`

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed the select query now, it was correct in the report.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I have deleted the table and created a new one.
Somehow this fixed it.

I ketp the same dataset and slq query, it still worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).